# XML metadata in Talend is not working for me. What else can I do?

Tags: xml, talend

I have a file that contains xml. I have tried to make a template from the metadata xml. It does read the xml, but it skips step 4 so I can't make a template. I also used xpath with the tFileinputxml and  tExtractxmlfield but it isn't giving me the correct output. Or maybe I'm doing something wrong.

I have used tFileinputxml and tExtractxmlfield to extract the data via xpath. But now it doesn't give me the correct values that I am asking.
For this I used an online xmlparser: https://easycodeforall.com/generate-xpath.html, I have gotten all possibilities for the xpath but it still doesn't work in Talend. I only get the first line of the entry.

What I actually want is the value of the entry and not the key value. And to also get the entry values of all rows, not just from the first line.

XML Example:

```
<properties>
  <entry key="color">#FF0000</entry>
  <entry key="size">medium</entry>
  <entry key="quantity">42</entry>
  <entry key="weight">2.5 kg</entry>
  <entry key="shape">round</entry>
  <entry key="material">cotton</entry>
  <entry key="price">$19.99</entry>
  <entry key="manufacturer">Acme Corp</entry>
  <entry key="rating">4.5 stars</entry>
  <entry key="model">XYZ123</entry>
</properties>
```

Xpath Example:

```
rows => "@key" (ignore rows see only entry and key)
entry => "/properties/entry"
key => "@key"
```

Example result in Talend:

```
.------------------+----------------------------------+------------------.
|                               tLogRow_3                                |
|=-----------------+----------------------------------+-----------------=|
|rows              |entry                             |key               |
|=-----------------+----------------------------------+-----------------=|
|key="color"       |<entry key="color">#FF0000</entry>|key="color"       |
|key="size"        |<entry key="color">#FF0000</entry>|key="size"        |
|key="quantity"    |<entry key="color">#FF0000</entry>|key="quantity"    |
|key="weight"      |<entry key="color">#FF0000</entry>|key="weight"      |
|key="shape"       |<entry key="color">#FF0000</entry>|key="shape"       |
|key="material"    |<entry key="color">#FF0000</entry>|key="material"    |
|key="price"       |<entry key="color">#FF0000</entry>|key="price"       |
|key="manufacturer"|<entry key="color">#FF0000</entry>|key="manufacturer"|
|key="rating"      |<entry key="color">#FF0000</entry>|key="rating"      |
|key="model"       |<entry key="color">#FF0000</entry>|key="model"       |
'------------------+----------------------------------+------------------'
```

Answer (score 0):

To make it easier for yourself, use the Metadata section of the app to create your structure, it's much easier to test the outcome prior to building a job.

You just need a file that contains your XML.

[image: Create File XML]

[image: XML Step 2]

[image: XML Step 4]

For what it's worth, remove the `lengths` and `precisions` ...

[image: XML Step 5]

... and save.

Now use that in your flow in a `tExtractXmlField` component.

[image: tXmlExtractField]

```
Starting job XML_Extract at 08:57 05/04/2023.
[statistics] connecting to socket on port 3891
[statistics] connected
.------------+-----------.
|       tLogRow_1        |
|=-----------+----------=|
|Key         |Entry_Value|
|=-----------+----------=|
|color       |#FF0000    |
|size        |medium     |
|quantity    |42         |
|weight      |2.5 kg     |
|shape       |round      |
|material    |cotton     |
|price       |$19.99     |
|manufacturer|Acme Corp  |
|rating      |4.5 stars  |
|model       |XYZ123     |
'------------+-----------'

[statistics] disconnected

Job XML_Extract ended at 08:57 05/04/2023. [Exit code  = 0]
```

Comment: I have tried to use the metadata as you're saying. I have opened the file with notepad++ and it says utf-8. When I use the metadata section, it goes until step 3. It does load the schema viewer, as in I can see the node elements. But when I click "Next" it loads but I stay on the step 3 view and when I click "Next" again it goes to step 5 but it doesn't load and it stays on step 3 view with an error that says: "At least one item must exist on Schema". I am not sure if its Talend itself or it's the file securities. Do you know how to solve this?

Comment: Show the screenshots then of what you’re talking about.

Comment: ... also, if that doesn't work, just replicate the settings I've shown above in the `tExtractXmlField` component.